# preempt one Thread for another on run-time in java

Tags: java

how to start and run a new, most important, thread by stopping current processing thread in JAVA. i.e. a current thread's processing is going  on and we want to stop or halt this thread for some time and execute a new thread.

Comment: You want to create a thread, start it and before calling the another thread, you need to stop the 1st thread? Then whats the point of creating threads, if your going to stop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such fine grain control over threads in Java. You normally try to stay away from thread priorities, as it generates brittle system. But if you absolutely must, you can change a threads priority and it will be taken into consideration by most systems.

```
Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY-1); // make it important
```

You can pause other threads only if they do support this. But keep in mind that a paused thread still does occupy all memory and resources. The work needed to pause and resume a thread might not be justified by the gains. (In this regard priorities are better).

To pause a thread you can for example use a lock which you aquire in the worker thread. Whenever it is locked (by a more important thread) it will make the worker thread pause (with no CPU usage).

```
class WorkerThread {
  Semaphore sem;

  void checkForPause() throws InterruptedExec{
    synchronized(sem) { // make sure unpauseThread() cant release it
      sem.aquire(); // will block when pauseThread aquired one
      sem.release();
    }
  }

  void pauseThread() {
    sem.aquire();
  }

  void unpauseThread() {
    synchronized(sem) { sem.release(); } // only release after checkForPause()
  }

  work run() {
    while(true) { // do something in a loop
      checkForPause();
      // do actual work in small steps
    }
  }
}
```

Now the WorkerThread instance can be controled with pauseThread() and unpauseThread().

BTW: in older Java there was `Thread#suspend()` and `Thread#resume()` but it should not be used in modern programs. In the [deprecation notice](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html) is some alternative code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Thread's Class join() method.

Let say if you have 2 threads T1 and T2.
When you call `T1.start()` , `T1.join()` and call `T2.start()` then T1 will wait until T2 finishes it work and after that T1 is going to execute.

Please go through the below link for more details.

[Thread join() method](http://www.journaldev.com/1024/java-thread-join-example-with-explanation)